# semantic-ui tab and javascript

Tags: semantic-ui

using semantic-ui tab control, I did found some answers in 
[Using the tab control in semantic-ui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21769214/using-the-tab-control-in-semantic-ui/21814094#21814094)

I downloaded the package from semantic-ui, opened up feed.html and modified the following:

```
<body id="feed">
        <div class="ui secondary pointing menu">
        <a class="active item">
            <i class="home icon"></i>Home</a>
        <a class="item">
            <i class="mail icon"></i>Messages</a>
        <a class="item">
            <i class="user icon"></i>Friends</a>

    </div>
    </body>
```

and it was not working

using what I found in [Using the tab control in semantic-ui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21769214/using-the-tab-control-in-semantic-ui/21814094#21814094), I changed to:

```
<div class="ui secondary pointing menu">
        <a class="active item">
            <i class="home icon"></i>Home</a>
        <a class="item">
            <i class="mail icon"></i>Messages</a>
        <a class="item">
            <i class="user icon"></i>Friends</a>

    </div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/d93af/19/

can someone point me on how to properly use semantic-ui?

also, is there a page like bootstrap:
http://getbootstrap.com/javascript
where it not only explains, but also show you some sample code?

I can't find such information in semantic-ui site.

thanks for the help!

Comment: https://semantic-ui.com/modules/tab.html#/examples

Answer (score 7):

You can use .on('click') to change class active:

http://jsfiddle.net/d93af/22/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.ui .item').on('click', function() {
      $('.ui .item').removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');
   });             
});
```

Comment: thanks for sharing, I did this and start to think... this should be taking cared of instead of me adding the script. Like bootstrap, after including the bootstrap.js, it does things for you.

Answer (score 7):

You need to initiate with jQuery
Here is the working example

```
<div class="ui grid page">
    <div class="column">
        <div class="ui pointing secondary menu" id="tabsTwo">
            <a class="active red item" data-tab="first">One</a>
            <a class="blue item" data-tab="second">Two</a>
            <a class="green item" data-tab="third">Three</a>
        </div>
        <div class="ui active tab segment" data-tab="first">First</div>
        <div class="ui tab segment" data-tab="second">Second</div>
        <div class="ui tab segment" data-tab="third">Third</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And use this script to initiate

```
$('.menu .item').tab();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".item").click(function(){
    $(".active").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
    var tab = $(this).attr("data-tab");
    $(".tab.segment").removeClass("active");
    $(".tab.segment[data-tab=\"" + tab + "\"]").addClass("active");
});
```

Comment: Can you please explain how this answers the question?

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.  Code-only answers are discouraged.